# Where is supplementaryViewOfKind used?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to figure out where `supplementaryViewOfKind` is used. I looked into the documentation and some other questions on SO, still I wasn't able to understand what it does. From my understanding it's to be used as an *auxiliary* Headerview.

```
collectionView.registerClass(imageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "imageCell")

collectionView.registerClass(imageCell2.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell2"
```

Can't I alternatively have imageCell2 registered this way:

```
collectionView.registerClass(imageCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "imageCell2")
```

and then when I need, at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I switch cases for the which cell to present? or again am I not understand the existensial purpose of `supplementaryViewOfKind`

Comment: You don't normally use collection cells for the supplementary views. You use some other custom `UICollectionReusableView` for the headers and footers.

Comment: @rmaddy OK so where do you normally use supplementary views?

Comment: Typically section headers and footer. Much like in a table view. Ultimately it depends on the layout manager.

Comment: @rmaddy why not just similar to tableViews where we do : `tableView.registerClass(TaskHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TaskHeaderView")` we just do `collectionView.registerClass(TaskHeaderView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TaskHeaderView")
`

Comment: A table view only has section headers and footers. A collection view can have different types of supplementary views depending on the layout manager. So the naming convention is more generic.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh I didn't know that it had stuff other than header/footer. Like what? Can you elaborate more? That's basically the core what I don't know.

Comment: I don't know one off the top my head and I don't have access to the documentation at the moment. But look at the layout managers. Keep in mind that custom layout managers can define their own supplementary views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The shortest answer**

Watch this video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/205/

**The short answer**

The supplementary view, like its name, provides supplementary material that needs some data to be displayed properly. Cells and supplementary views can be closely related to each other or have little to do with each other.

The concept is a little different than `UITableView` so you might want to read below how it is different. In short, `UICollectionView` is intended so people can have a group of/groups of views laid out in a non-linear way, according to their own rules.

**Example**

Let's say I made a map using `UICollectionView`. I could use `UICollectionViewCell`s to display buildings.

Here, I can use the supplementary view in infinitely different ways.

I can choose to use it as a label to display the name of town. In this case I would be using one supplementary view for one section.

OR I can use supplementary view to display the name of each building. In this case I would have the same number of supplementary views and cells.

OR I could actually do both, registering different classes to the same collection view.

**UICollectionView vs UITableView**

It's easy to get confused because the terminology used for `UICollectionView` is similar to what is used in `UITableView`, but it's crucial to know the differences between the two in order to understand what things do in collection view.

a) It has a layout object whose main concern is the display of cells registered to the collection view. As far as I remember the stock `UICollectionViewLayout` does nothing, or provides minimal layout functionality whereas the `UITableView` class has a built-in way of laying out its cells--i.e. a linear vertical row.

b) You define the rules through the layout object. This rule governs how things--cells, supplementary views--are displayed in the collection view.

c) Because the collection view is intended so you define a custom layout object, so as to display a set of objects(i.e. cells, supplementary views) following a certain rule (i.e. the rules defined by the layout object) that aren't laid out in a linear manner, there's no real sense of "section header" in a collection view. A section header in a table view is a view object that provides the title or summary of what is in the section. A supplementary view doesn't have this "one per section" limitation. You can use it like a section header if you want, but you don't have to.

d) As mentioned in the example, you can register many different kinds of supplementary views. It's not like the table view where you only get a header and a footer.

e) The `section` and `item` in the `IndexPath` are just logical groups. (Notice `UICollectionView` doesn't use the term `row`, since it doesn't assume cells will be laid out in a row) Cells in a section don't even have to be laid out close to each other if that's how the layout rules are defined in the layout object.

f) The index path of cells and that of supplementary views have no connection with each other unless you decide to logically group them together. You can have cells but no supplementary views, the same number of both, or more supplementary views than the cells. They are two different discrete entities unless you choose to logically group them and use them together.

g) In case people want a somewhat linear but different from `UITableView` look (e.g. a horizontally scrolled table view or 4x4 layout of pictures), Apple provides `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout`. Using this you can have the table view like behavior, as well as the header and footer as supplementary views.

Comment: If the OP is also confused about the decoration view, I can also explain. Understanding the differences between the table view and the collection view takes a little time.

Comment: Best thing about this answer was the WWDC video, The first 10 minutes was enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better check this article:

[Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH1-SW1)

In the section [Custom Layouts: A Worked Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH8-SW6), you can find an example of custom layout using Supplementary View.

[image]

In the example above, connecting lines are implemented using Supplementary Views.

You can use Supplementary Views in various ways with your custom layouts.

Comment: At first I thought I was suppose to read what's in your image...then I realized this whole image is a custom collectionView

Comment: @Honey, yes, all blue rects are cells. Unfortunately, the article I have shown lacks a link to the working sample code. You can find a "re-implemented in Swift" version [here](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/CustomLayoutsWorked-Swift).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out where supplementaryViewOfKind is used

A layout can define supplementary view kinds however it likes, to give you a way to specify things that are not ordinary cells (items).

A good example is the way UICollectionViewFlowLayout lets you ask for section headers and footers. They are supplementary views. In particular, they are supplementary views of kind `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` and `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/flow_layout_supplementary_views).

In my Latin app's list of chapters and sections, the chapters (black bars with white numbers at left) are supplementary views:

[image]

Comment: Can you add images (for the not ordinary cell) to make it more elaborative?

Comment: You can add anything you like. There are no rules about what goes into a supplementary view.

Answer (score 0):

The supplementaryViews are the **Paris** and **Chamonix** in the image Below.
They are neither the header, nor the footer nor the cell. They are something else. Similar to cells you would have register them and then also dequeue them, or that they also do take data from the dataSource so in that sense they are data driven, but they just don't contain data for the cells, they contain *meta* data...

Just jump to minute 5:47 of this [WWDDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/205/). Though I suggest you to see the entire video from beginning.

[image]